# Compute Euclidean distance matrix using one for-loop PYTHON

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop, euclidean-distance

PYTHON

How can I compute the Euclidean distance matrix using only one for-loop.
Note: only make use of Numpy, not other packages.

Thank you in advance.

This is my code using two for-loops:

```
m = 10
X = np.random.randint(10, size =(m,m))
D = np.zeros((m,m), dtype = int)
for i in range(0, m):
    for j in range(0, m):
        v = X[i,:] - X[j,:]
        D[i][j] = np.linalg.norm(v)
D
```

Comment: Answer part 1, - Only `numpy`,  - `X` is `Y`

Comment: Yes, this partially answers my question. Thank you for that. But do you also know how to do it with exactly one for-loop?

Comment: there's no benefit to using a `for` loop in `numpy` when you can broadcast.   The restriction of using *exactly* one `for` loop sounds suspiciously like a professor trying to keep you from seeking answers on SO.  Assuming that's the case, I'll throw you a bread crumb - `np.ix_` will give you two lists of indices you can `zip` together and do in one loop.  You *shouldn't*, you don't *have to*, but you *can*.

Comment: It is indeed an exercise the prof gave us lol. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need any loop for this.

`np.linalg.norm((X[None, :, :] - X[:, None, :]), axis=-1)` will give you the matrix.